# mathquill latex- how can I move cursor (selection) by code?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathquill

I am using mathquill lib ([mathquill git](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill)) and I am trying to make a keypad and a backspace using html buttons but I can't figure out how to move the cursor throw the formula.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger custom keydown event on textarea within mathquill to move cursor through formula.

```
var customKeyDownEvent = $.Event('keydown');

customKeyDownEvent.bubbles = true;
customKeyDownEvent.cancelable =true;
customKeyDownEvent.charCode = 37;  // 37 for left arrow key
customKeyDownEvent.keyCode = 37;   
customKeyDownEvent.which = 37;

$('.mathquill-editable textarea').trigger(customKeyDownEvent);
```

Use charCode / keyCode / which are:

1. 37 for left arrow key
2. 39 for right arrow key

Thanks.